# How can I change header height in react native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

i just want to give more height to the navigation header. i just added `height: 360` to the `headerStyle` but nothing is changed. i couldn't find any other solution

[image]

app.tsx

```js
<Stack.Screen
                    name='Item Picture'
                    component={ItemPicture}
                    options={({ navigation }) => ({
                        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red', height: 360 },
                        headerTitleStyle: {
                            fontFamily: 'SFProRegular',
                            color: '#ffffff',
                        },
                        headerTransparent: true,
                        headerLeft: () => (
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.goBack}>
                                <Image
                                    source={require(chevronlight)}
                                    style={{
                                        height: 20,
                                        width: 13,
                                    }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        ),
                    })}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the height to the stack.navigator tag just like the one you have given to stack.screen?